# Is there a way to bin data using a mathematical sequence approach in R?

Tags: r, math, sequence, binning

I have 225,666 data points, with each data point containing 74 observations.

I would like to bin the data to reduce the number of data points, providing more manageable data analysis.

However, the data is not ordered in a particularly obvious way.

1, 2, 3, 4, 5...378

379, 380, 381, 382...756

repeated until

225288, 225289, 225290...225666 (i.e. 378 date points per line, for 597 lines).

I would like to bin this data.

As 225666 is divisible by 9, my thinking is that 81 data points per bin, i.e. 9 datapoints in the 'x' direction (e.g. 1-9 in line 1) followed by the corresponding 9 datapoints in the 'y' direction (e.g. 1, 379, 757...). I then require the mean of all the datapoints in this bin.

Currently, I have binned that data into 25,074 bins (i.e. in multiples of 9, but in the 'x' direction), but now I would like to further bin this data. **This may not be the best way to attempt this challenge.
**
I need bin 1, 42, 84, 126...336 (9 of these bins in multiples of 42) to form one larger bin. I would then like to repeat this so I have 2, 43, 85, 127, ...337 to form a second larger bin. This will then loop up until that 41, 125...377 form a bin. I will also the need 378, 420, 462... form bins, and so on until I have 597 larger bins.

Unless there is a more competent way to reach this goal?

Comment: Show us what the file looks like in an editor (or show `str(dat)` if you have already done the `read.*` step)

Comment: While 225,666 is divisible by 9, your row count 597 isn't. So you could bin your data into 9x9 subsquares, but then you'll have 3 lines left over.

Comment: I must admit, I'm pretty confused by the structure too. Your first line say *"each data point containing 74 observations"*, but that 74 number isn't mentioned again - how is it relevant? I **think** you're telling us that your data is a 597 row by 378 column matrix or data frame, but you don't say that directly so I'm not really sure... is it that or something else? And is there any reason to do this binning iteratively, first making small bins, and then binning the bins? Seems like it would be more straightforward to directly calculate whatever means you're after.

Comment: Sorry for any confusion. The file is actually 225,666 rows by 74 columns (observations). However, these correspond to areas in space, being that the first 378 rows are all constant across a y axis but change by their location of the x axis. The next 378 lines are on different y axis, but constant for all 378, and vary in y axis.

As for binning iteratively, I thought this would be easier to start, rather than attempting to bin 9 adjacent rows with the 9 rows that correspond to the same x co-ordinate but different y co-ordinate. But maybe this over complicates it for me?

Comment: 1 2 3 4 … 378 (next line)//

379 380 381 382 … 756

^^ this is how data was obtained, if you picture a large square, then there is datapoints collected per line, for 597 lines. Each datapoint contains 74 observations (i.e. information regarding that one 'pixel')
the read out data is:

row 1: 1,2,3,4...74 (where each number is a meaningful observation
row 2: 1,2,3,4...74
...
row 225,666: 1,2,3,4...74

I know that row 1 and row 2 are adjacent, meaning are same y axis plane. And then row 397 is the same x axis plane as row 1, but differing y co-ordinate.

hopefully this clarifies?

Comment: Ah, that's clearer. I think the iterative binning overcomplicates. I see two possible solutions, (a) make a for loop and do a little math to find the write cells and calculate the means directly, (b) reshape your data into a 3-dimensional array so it is 378 x 597 x 74, and calculate the "column means" over the correct dimension to get your result. It would help **a lot** if you could illustrate your problem at a smaller scale by sharing sample data that is very clear what values need to be binned together...

Comment: ...could you create and share some sample data where there are, for example, where each data point consists of 4 observations, and there are 3 data points per line for 5 lines, or something like that? And just give each value a number corresponding to a bin, so we know we want to bin all the 1s together, and all the 2s together, etc? A small example like that would help immensely.